# Assumptions in general linear model and in multivariate linear regression model?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am reading Wikipedia and some notes I found online, and still not very clear about their definitions. Both the general linear model and the multivariate linear regression model assume
$$
   Y = X\beta + e
$$
where $Y$ is $n \times q$, $X$ is $n \times p$, $\beta$ is $p \times q$, and $e$ is $n \times q$. $n$ is sample size, $p$ is the number of input variables, and $q$ is the number of output variables.

What does the general linear model further assume?

What does the multivariate linear regression model further assume?

For example, following are some assumptions that I can think of on the model, more specifically, on the error matrix $e$.

- the mean of every entry of $e$ is zero
- Any two entries of $e$ in the same column but different rows are uncorrelated
- Any two entries of $e$ in different columns and different rows are uncorrelated
- All entries of $e$ in the same column but different rows have the same variance.

If all of above assumptions hold, can the estimation be done for each output variable separately?

If not all of the above assumptions hold, is it good to estimate for each output variable separately?

Comment: What distinction are you making between "general linear model" & "multivariate linear regression model"?

Comment: @Scortchi: general linear model doesn't assume anything on the errors, except their expectations are zero. I am not sure about how people generally assume on multivariate linear regression model?

Comment: If you're not the one making a distinction, what reason to suppose there is one? I'd just call the latter a special case of the former ($q>1$). And note that often enough general linear models come with several more assumptions than a conditional expectation of zero.